# $\sigma$-finite measures can be approximated by finite measures

Tags: limits, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $(X, \beta, \mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose $\mu$ is a $\sigma-$finite measure ($X = \cup E_n$ with $\mu(E_n) < \infty$). Prove that there exist finite measures $\mu_n$ such that $\mu(B) = \lim_{n->\infty} \mu_n(B)$ for all $B$ in $\beta$.

Attempt:

Define $\mu_n(B) = \mu(B \cap F_n)$ where $F_n = \cup_{i = 1}^{n} E_i$.

Define $B_n = B \cap F_n$. Then $B_n \subseteq B_{n+1}$ for all $n$. By the MCT for measurable sets, $\lim_{n->\infty} \mu_n(B) = \lim_{n->\infty} \mu(B_n) = \mu(\lim_{n->\infty} B_n)$

By definition, $\lim_{n -> \infty} B_n = \cup_{i = 1}^{\infty} B_i = B \cap X = B$.

Thus $\lim_{n->\infty} \mu_n(B) = \mu(B)$.

Comment: You can not show since it does not necessarily go to zero, consider real line as a sigma-finite space with Lebesgue measure and it is of course countable union of [-N,N] intervals But the complement set has infinite measure.. You can just show it by monotone convergence theorem directly.

Comment: Sorry, show precisely what by the monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: Should I say that $\mu(B \cap F_n) \le \mu(B \cap F_{n+1})$ and $\mu(B \cap F_n) \le \mu(B \cap X)$? This shows that it is increasing and bounded above, but how do I show that the supremum of $\mu(B \cap F_n)$ is indeed $\mu(B \cap X)$?

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem, says that if E1,E2,... is a sequence with $E_1\subset E_2$,...,$E_i\subset E_{i+1}$,.... Then the measure of the union $\cup  E_i$ is the limit of $\cup_1^nE_i$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: But I cannot apply it to the $E_i$ directly. Do I apply it to $B \cap F_n$?

Comment: Yes, just apply it to $B\cap F_n$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is it correct now? @stephenkk

Comment: I wonder what is $\lim_{n\to \infty} B_n$?

Comment: @ArcticChar It is basically the theorem that stephen mentioned